# Front page identification and page--front template not working

Tags: 8, uri, redirection

After install [URL Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/url_redirect) module not able to check the current page is front page or not by programmatically. Following code does not return anything:

`\Drupal::service('path.matcher')->isFrontPage()`

Also page--front.html.twig template getting removed from front page template suggestion.